# Как в js вывести время в виде ч.м.с если пользователь вводит время в секундах?

Tags: javascript

Только начинаю познавать js, большая просьба объяснить, буду очень признателен.

Comment: `(sec/3600|0) + '.' +(sec/60%60|0) + '.' + (sec%60)`

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: это в общих чертах. Там нужно ещё минуты/секунды нулями дополнить, если меньше десяти.